# How to use the built-in variables FS an RS in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

This is the content of a file i am working with.

```
<Overall>1
<Value>2
<Rooms>3
<Location>4

<Overall>5
<Value>6
<Rooms>7
<Location>8
```

My attempt was

```
 awk ' BEGIN{ FS="<.*>"; RS=""; } { print $2 } ' $1
```

Desired output

```
1
5
```

Actual output

```
4
8
```

Could someone point out what where mistake is?

Comment: try `FS="<[^>]+>"`

Comment: .. or try adding a more robust `FPAT`

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot sir.

Comment: @RadoslavTodorov : You can _accept_ the answer by clicking on the tick mark left of the Answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk ' BEGIN{ FS="<[^>]+>"; RS=""; } { print $2 } ' inputfile
```

Modify the `FS` value to `FS="<[^>]+>"` . Or as suggested by Inian , Go for defining field contents using `FPAT`.

`<[^>]+>` Means, `<` followed by anything(one or more) which is not equal to `>`  till `>`.